# How to use padding/margin automatically on TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to use padding for the text except the first line. It's hard to use `\t` because the length of each lines varies in each phone.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over
    the lazy dog near the river 
    Thames in the City of London.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is create two different Textviews

Comment: I've thought of that. But if the device has high DPI it will create a lot of empty space at the end of each line. If low, then the text will overflow to the next line. Either way, it will break the design of the TextView.